# Accuracy decreased after using google word2vec model for a sentiment classification [NLP][word-embedding]

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I am using Amazon fine food reviews for a sentiment classification project. while I used my dataset corpus to train avg word2vec , I was getting an accuracy of 89 %.
by using BOW and TF-IDF, i was getting 91 AND 92 % respectively.
But after using google news word2vec dataset and applying avg word2vec to train a LR model, accuracy decreased to 84%. what could be possible reasons , what should  I check ?